# SwiftUI - Multiple alignmentGuides in Stacks

Tags: swiftui, alignment, vertical-alignment

Is there a way to specify multiple alignment guides across SwiftUI stack views (`HStack`/`VStack`)?

I do have a basic view setup like the following

```swift
HStack {
    VStack { ... }
    VStack { ... }
    VStack { ... }
    VStack { ... }
    VStack { ... }
}
```

Inside this `VStack`s I do have text with different font sizes.

[image]

As you can see on the screenshot, I was able to align the `Text` inside the `VStack`. I did that using the basic `.alignmentGuide` feature.

However, it seems that the system applies 'offsets' for the whole `VStack` and not just for the `Text` view.

Is it possible to:

- restrict the 'alignment' only to the `Text` view? (I can imagine that this is not possible as it could break other layouts
- add another 'alignment' to the other elements as well?

---

Example code:

```swift
extension VerticalAlignment {
    /// A custom alignment for image titles.
    private struct TimeTextAlignment: AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in context: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
            // Default to bottom alignment if no guides are set.
            context[VerticalAlignment.firstTextBaseline]
        }
    }

    /// A guide for aligning titles.
    static let timeTextAlignment = VerticalAlignment(
        TimeTextAlignment.self
    )
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let textSize: Double = 70
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .timeTextAlignment) {
            ChildView(value: "5", textSize: textSize)
            ChildView(value: "0", textSize: textSize)
            ChildView(value: ":", textSize: textSize)
            ChildView(value: "0", textSize: textSize)
            ChildView(value: "0", textSize: textSize)
            ChildView(value: "0", textSize: textSize, small: true)
            ChildView(value: "0", textSize: textSize, small: true)
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    let value: String
    let textSize: Double
    let small: Bool

    init(value: String, textSize: Double, small: Bool = false) {
        self.value = value
        self.textSize = textSize
        self.small = small
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {

            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.up")
            }

            Spacer()

            Text(value)
                .font(.system(size: small ? textSize * 0.5 : textSize))
                .alignmentGuide(.timeTextAlignment) { context in
                    context[.firstTextBaseline]
                }

            Spacer()

            Button {

            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
            }
        }
        .background(Color.red)
    }
}
```

*Full playground can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1T0dMU7u5AVwYPqWY5mmIssKdYMIN7nXP)*

---

As a 'workaround' I could imagine that I could restructure the Views into three `HStacks` inside one `VStack`.

Comment: An example should be included in the question as code not a link.

Comment: Thank you I updated the original question and but the code in there as well.